# spotfire dynamic tables script

Tags: spotfire

I have different categories and for each category the data has different columns. I want to create a cross table visualization in Spotfire where if I select the category the data table related to that category displays in cross table. Basically I want to make chose data table option dynamic in cross table visualization. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your data table as an input to Data function (R Function) and in that you can Dcast it and plot output as Table.